# How to import class application from another directory into tabbedpanel kivy

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy, python-import

I have made a calculator application. I am trying to make a GUI with the use of kivy. I have a tabbedpanel, and I am having trouble importing the calculator app to the first tab in the tabbedpanel. These are the two files I am working with, the calulator.py and the panel.py. Thank you for any feedback.

calculator.py:

```
`import kivy
from kivy.app import App 

# making of button to arrange me
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
 
# for the size of window
from kivy.config import Config

# Setting size to resizable
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', 1)
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '400')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '400')
 
 
# Creating Layout class
class CalcGridLayout(GridLayout):
  
    # Function called when equals is pressed
    def calculate(self, calculation):
        if calculation:
            try:
                # Solve formula and display it in entry
                # which is pointed at by display
                self.display.text = str(eval(calculation))
            except Exception:
                self.display.text = "Error"
  
 # Creating App class
class CalculatorApp(App):
  
    def build(self):
        return CalcGridLayout()
  
# creating object and running it
calcApp = CalculatorApp()
calcApp.run()` 

panel.py:

    '''
TabbedPanel
============

Test of the widget TabbedPanel.
'''


from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel
from kivy.lang import Builder

import sys
sys.path.append("../Python GUI")
from Calculator.calculator import *


Builder.load_string("""

<Test>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
    do_default_tab: False

    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Tab 1'
 
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Tab 2'
        BoxLayout:
            Label:
                text: 'Second tab content area'
            Button:
                text: 'Button that does nothing'
    TabbedPanelItem:
        text: 'Tab 3'
        RstDocument:
            text:
                '\\n'.join(("Hello world", "-----------",
                "You are in the third tab."))

""")


class Test(TabbedPanel):
    pass


class TabbedPanelApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Test()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TabbedPanelApp().run()
```

I would like the calculator to show in the first tab

Comment: Why don't you just add your `CalcGridLayout` to the first `TabbedPanelItem` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the appclass in kv by using `app.` . So for example if you want to access the property `name` of the app class it would look like this in kv

```
text:app.name
```

Comment: So how would I display my calculator application in the first tab of my tabbedpanel?